# Boxplot on a continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

The aim of this is to put the box plot of various observations onto one scale to visualise the effects of number influence (density damaged) as compared to the plant size.

The data is as follows:

```
Site    Type    zscores
D19     tea     -2.094295799
D119    tea     -1.758031135
D119    tea     -0.41697259
D119    tea     -2.154827157
O15     tea     0.472853048
O15     tea     1.121169921
O15     tea     0.676107338
O15     tea     1.244862196
O15     tea     1.351503732
O15     tea     -1.918836703
O15     tea     -2.665327454
O15     tea     -0.95906288
O15     tea     1.12044707
O15     tea     0.538872924
O15     tea     -2.11275879
O15     tea     0.955244846
O15     tea     -0.841728712
O29     rose    -1.220383412
O29     rose    -2.046877257
O29     rose    -1.046225646
O29     rose    -1.894125458
```

At this stage the only graph I get drawn is the following boxplot:

```
ggplot(data = types, aes(Site, zscores, fill = Type)) +
geom_boxplot()
```

That results in this:

[image]

How can I get the different sites bars to move to the **density damaged plants** within a site?

The idea is to have a continuous scale like this but using boxplots instead of simple point and standard error, example of density on x axis with mean points and SE:
[image]

Comment: There was 300 plants observed per site

Comment: Do you have a variable that has the the density damaged plants value in it?

Comment: The density damaged plants per site is equal to the number of observations/300, as I already removed the undamaged plants from the data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a long and tedious way. That works, but not 100% yet.
This method does use `ggplot` to plot the graph

```
library(ggplot2)
types <- read.csv("data/stack.csv")
head(types)

##Site Type    zscores
##1  D19  tea -2.0942958
##2 D119  tea -1.7580311
##3 D119  tea -0.4169726
##4 D119  tea -2.1548272
##5  O15  tea  0.4728530
##6  O15  tea  1.1211699

sitelevels <- levels(types$Site) ##extract all the different sites
##[1] "D119" "D19"  "H42"  "L20"  "L55"  "O15"  "O29"  "O30"  "O32"  "O43"  "O44"  "O45"  "O47"  "O50" 
##[15] "O63"  "O68"  "O83"  "O85"  "W15c" "W17c" "W21b" "W27a" "W28a" "X27a" "X27b" "X29a" "X29b" "X29c"
```

This is needed to calculate the density for each of the separate sites as the number of plants investigated were 300 across all of the sites and only the damaged plants are left in the `types` data set

```
avedens <- c() ##Empty vector to store the site densities in
c<- 1

for(c in c(1:length(sitelevels))){  ##runs a for loop for the number of sites
  avedens[c] <- nrow(subset(types, types$Site == comps[c]))/300 ##calculate the value for each site and store it in avedens
}

use <- data.frame(site = sitelevels, density = avedens) ## create a table with the site names and corresponding densities

head(use)

##site     density
##1 D119 0.010000000
##2  D19 0.003333333
##3  H42 0.016666667
##4  L20 0.036666667
##5  L55 0.096666667
##6  O15 0.043333333
```

From this table the site density values are assigned to each of the separate observations.

```
x <- 1

for(x in c(1:nrow(types))){ ##for loop to assign the plot density value to each of the separate observations
  types$dens[x] <- use$density[use$site == types$Site[x]] ##assign the right value using the site names to correlate the correct values
}

head(types)
  ##Site Type    zscores        dens
##1  D19  tea -2.0942958 0.003333333
##2 D119  tea -1.7580311 0.010000000
##3 D119  tea -0.4169726 0.010000000
##4 D119  tea -2.1548272 0.010000000
##5  O15  tea  0.4728530 0.043333333
##6  O15  tea  1.1211699 0.043333333
```

The boxplot is then drawn using the density (`dens`) on the X-axis and the zscore on the Y-axis with `ggplot`
    ggplot(data = types, aes(dens, zscores, fill = Site)) +
      geom_boxplot() ## draw the boxplot

[Boxplots at the correct positions as a points graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tlad.png)

the only problem now is to get all of the boxes the same widths

Comment: Would the thin boxes be due to the sites having the same damage density?